# Python - MySQLdb - Updating row causes TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mysql

I've tried this many ways and I cant seem to figure it out but anyway here is what im doing:

```
threadupdatequery = "UPDATE %s SET topic_name=%%s, subject_name=%%s, poster_name=%%s, time=%%s, image=%%s, replies=%%s, id=%%s, keywords=%%s, text=%%s WHERE id=%%s" % ('Threads')
...
(topic, subject, name, time, image, replies, ID, kw, body) = self.tframe.Get()
cur.execute(threadupdatequery, (topic, subject, name, time, image, replies, ID, kw, body))
```

Originally I did this which I had no doubt would work but I was wrong:

```
cur.execute(threadupdatequery, self.tframe.Get())
```

I keep getting:

```
File "C:\Python27\Work\SiteEditor.py", line 216, in UpdateThread
cur.execute(threadupdatequery, (topic, subject, name, time, image, replies, ID, kw, body))
File "C:\Python27-32Bit\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 184, in execute
query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Usually I make some silly mistake but I just don't see it this time...

Thanks :)

Comment: 10 times %%s but only 9 variables in execute() -> missing last id ?

Comment: Wow thats not at all what I expected but yeah that was it thank you very much, I totally forgot about the `WHERE id=%%s` part

Comment: added as answer, feel free to accept if it solved your problem ;-)

Comment: It's more convenient to use dictionary formatting ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the update query has 10 `%%s` placeholders, but the execute() call has only 9 replacement variables. the last `WHERE id=%%s` can not be replaced. if you add the missing variable it will probably work.